# How to set the customised priority for my dropdown options

Tags: javascript

I am getting drop down values from dackend as a JSON String object.My Json String contains 2 values one is id and another one is e_name.Now i am dispalying e_name in my dropdown.

```
script language="JavaScript">
function getEnvNames(result){
    $("#environmentDetails").empty();
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {

        $("#environmentDetails").append("<option>" + value.environments_name  + "</option>");

    });

}
</script>
```

This is my JSON object

```
{"id":3272,"C_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"},{"id"
:3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"
},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"},{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},
{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"
}]
```

like this e_name values are there.I am displaying these values in my drop down.

```
    HCL - Demo
   IBM1 - Test
    ECO1 - Development
    MindSpace - Development
    ABC - Demo
   CDF - Test
   FGR - Production
   RFGGDDF - Production
```

If my dropdown option contains pro like (FGR - Production),i want to  give first priority.then if my drop down contains devevelopement(MindSpace - Development) then i have to give 2nd priority.like test-3rd priority Demo
 (ABC - Demo).4th priority test( CDF - Test)
..

My Doubt is how to set the customized priority for my drop down options.

Like this i am getting my JSON String object from Backend.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/environments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("selectedcustomername"+selectedcustomername);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());
         List<Environments>  environmentnamesList= loginD.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         System.out.println("gson"+gson);
         String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
         return jsonString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Now I think your problem may sort....

```
    function getEnvNames(result) {$("#environmentDetails").empty();
    var data = new Array(), newarr = new Array();
    data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("pro") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("dev") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("test") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) { $("#environmentDetails").append("<option>" + newarr[i] + "</option>");}
    });}

 Output

 infosys - pro  
 ibm - pro  
 hcl - dev  
 ibm -  test  
 emc - test
```

Comment: And If you getting data from back-end then before converting your data in json format , You can sort this easily. Only assign data to ddl in jquery function.

Comment: I updated my question how i am getting my JSON String object.Can you tell me how to filter in backend.

Comment: Hi Swetha , I am working in .NET technology , I can do this using Linq To Sql in backend But i think , you will not get . So I am giveing you solution in jquery only so that you can get,.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Like this you can set the customised priority for dropdown options.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onLoad() {
    var temparr = new Array(),newarr = new Array();
    temparr.push("hcl - dev");
    temparr.push("ibm - test");
    temparr.push("infosys - pro");
    temparr.push("ibm - pro");
    temparr.push("emc - test");
    select = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
    for (var i = 0; i < temparr.length; i++) {  if (temparr[i].search("pro") > 0) {  newarr.push(temparr[i]); temparr.splice(i,1);i = i - 1; }}
    for (var i = 0; i < temparr.length; i++) { if (temparr[i].search("dev") > 0) { newarr.push(temparr[i]); temparr.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; }}
    for (var i = 0; i < temparr.length; i++) { if (temparr[i].search("test") > 0) { newarr.push(temparr[i]); temparr.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; }}
    for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) { select.add(new Option(newarr[i]));}
    window.event.returnValue = false;return false; 
}
```

OutPut

```
infosys - pro  
ibm - pro  
hcl - dev  
ibm -  test  
emc - test
```

Comment: what is DropDownList1.

Comment: I have taken one drop down list... <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">

Comment: just now i updated my entire code and my problem clear.can you please take a look .update me accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

---

I am running this code in my system its working.....

```
   function getEnvNames(result) {
    debugger;
    $("#environmentDetails").empty();
    var data = new Array(), newarr = new Array();
    data = JSON.parse(result);
    if(data.length>0){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("pro") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("dev") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].search("test") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
    for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) { $("#environmentDetails").append("<option>" + newarr[i] + "</option>"); }}
    window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: i am getting  -----   data[i].search is not a function

Comment: If i tring to print data i am not getting any thing.like alert("dataaa"+data);My output is dataaa only.

Comment: Hi I modified some error in code, Just try it. And Make sure result variable string contain any value;

Comment: I think , whatever value you are returning from back-end , It is empty.

Comment: just now i updated my question very clearly.can you please take a alook

Comment: Check in back-end,  what value is returning " String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);" this line.

Comment: just now i updated my entire code and my problem clear.can you please take a look .update me accordingly

Comment: jsonString [{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"},{"id"
:3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"
},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"},{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},
{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"
}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96010/discussion-between-mvswetha-and-shravan-chaurasiya).

Comment: I have already given solution using your jason string. Just look new answer. I think it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

---

Now Check , I taken your jason string. Its working fine.

```
    function getEnvNames() {
    debugger;
    $("#environmentDetails").empty();
    var data = new Array(), newarr = new Array();
    var data = [{ "id": 3272, "company_name": "HCL - Demo" }, { "id": 3255, "company_name": "IBM1 - Test" }, { "id": 3257, "company_name": "ECO1 - Development" }, { "id": 3253, "company_name": "MindSpace - Development" }, { "id": 3256, "company_name": "ABC - Demo" }, { "id": 3258, "company_name": "CDF - Test" }, { "id": 3205, "company_name": "FGR - Production" }, { "id": 3208, "company_name": "RFGGDDF - Production"}];
    if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].company_name.search("Production") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].company_name.search("Development") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].company_name.search("Test") > 0) { newarr.push(data[i]); data.splice(i, 1); i = i - 1; } }
        for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) { $("#environmentDetails").append("<option>" + newarr[i].company_name + "</option>"); }
    }
    window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Output

```
<select name="environmentDetails" id="environmentDetails"><option>FGR - Production</option><option>RFGGDDF - Production</option><option>ECO1 - Development</option><option>MindSpace - Development</option><option>IBM1 - Test</option><option>CDF - Test</option></select>
```